# Web api call lost in dll function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dll

I am developing an web services in mvc asp.net 5.

I am using a SDK from a dll, but when I call a function from this dll it does not respond. It stays waiting an does not throw an error.

I am compiling in x86. This is the code

```
  public Respuesta TimbrarFactura(String ConceptoDocumento, String Serie, double Folio, String password)
    {
        try
        {
            int resp = SDK.fEmitirDocumento(ConceptoDocumento, Serie, Folio, password, "");
            if (resp == 0)
            {

                return new Respuesta(true, "Se timbro el documento");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SDK.fError(resp, sMensaje, 255);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

                return new Respuesta(false, sMensaje.ToString());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I added a try catch block to get some error, but the catch block is never entered. What could be causing this?

Comment: Were you able to debug the code? What value do you get in `resp`? Which method of SDK stays in await?

Comment: What is the exception?